# Operand type clash with time(7)

Tags: sql, database

I'm having the worst time trying to insert data into a table. The TimeoftheDay column has the variable of Time(7). I can't for the life of me get the format right. I get a "Operand type clash: int is incompatible with time" error and if I try to write the time a 07:30:00 I get a syntax error for the ':'. I've scoured the internet but I cannot get the format to work.

Here is the query that I'm trying to write:

```
Insert Into Class (CourseNumber, CourseName, TimeoftheDay, Room, RoomCapacity, CourseDescription, CreditHours)
    Values (1, 'Biology', 0800, 123, 30, 'Study Life', 4)
```

How am I suppose to write the data?

Answer (score 1):

Use a string to format the value:

```
Insert Into Class (CourseNumber, CourseName, TimeoftheDay, Room, RoomCapacity, CourseDescription, CreditHours)
    Values (1, 'Biology', '08:00', 123, 30, 'Study Life', 4)
```